# Upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 now

Tags: upgrade, arm, 22.04

I have read in many posts that it will be a few months before Ubuntu 20.04 asks to upgrade to 22.04.

Just now my RPi4 asked me if I want to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.

Question:

Is it just Ubuntu ARM64 that is ready to do upgrades or is AMD64 also ready to upgrade now.

Comment: I don't think you will get the upgrade popup in AMD64 until 22.04.1 is released in August 2022. As for Pi, I don't think RPi4 was officially supported in Ubuntu 20.04. The popup in Pi **may be** an artifact of the unofficial repositories for RPi4. This my guess.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is certified for the Raspberry Pi https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-20-04-lts-is-certified-for-the-raspberry-pi I think I downloaded my copy of 20.04 from: https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi